# Force Google Sheets to Use no Formatting on new Row

Tags: spreadsheet, zapier

I am using google sheets and Zapier to feed in new email data into a row.

Each row is colour coded depending on status and my problem is this......

Question:
When a new row is imported via Zapier, it automatically gets the background and text color from the previous row. This is really causing me problems, I need new lines to be normal (e.g. white background and black text).

Can anyone offer a solution please?

Comment: are you coloring the rows manually or using [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)?

Comment: using conditional formatting. thanks

Comment: can you update your question with what zapier action you're using, the conditions you're triggering on, and a screenshot of the improperly formatted row? I just tried it with the "Create New Row" action and my formatting was done correctly

Comment: yes but before you update new row change color of last row background, then try it.

Comment: like, modify the conditional formatting? it's all done automatically, so there's no need to change anything myself. rows just get added and are expressed in the correct color